# Laravel Model get next increment ID when the Table linked with Model is Non-AutoIncrement

Tags: mysql, laravel, model, increment, laravel-6

As I mentioned in Question, the current Laravel 6.0 project I am working on has bit weird DB setup, where the Model's(the MainModel here) MySQL table has been set with `AutoIncrement` as `NULL`. And client won't allow to change the Table's definition at all.

I want to reliably find the next and previous IDs of the Model(since I can't find from table as AutoIncrement is set to NULL) before inserting record, so that I can  make an entry of relevant record(for eg. image(s) of a testimonial/faq or any WYSIWYG content field) into another referential table first, by correctly inserting the main Model's ID into the refrential ID field of that another table.

Currently I have this in my main Model, but the `next` method doesn't reliably return the exact incremented ID consistently:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Te7aHoudini\LaravelTrix\Traits\HasTrixRichText;

class [MainModel] extends Model
{
    use HasTrixRichText;

    protected $guarded = [];
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $connection = '[connection1]';
    protected $table = '[main_table]';
    protected $fillable = ['id', '[titlefield]', '[wysiwyg_field]'];

    /**
     *  Setup model event hooks
     */
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        self::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->id = $model->max('id') + 1;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Get next available Faq Id
     */
    public function next()
    {
        return ++$this->id;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Hmmm... was writing up an answer, but got confused why next has that logic instead of reusing the approach of the boot method?

Comment: There's no reliable way to do it before the insert because a race condition could happen between identification and retrieval. `SELECT MAX(..) ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE`, `INSERT ` within the same transaction might have have some success. Do this in a loop to ensure success. Show the client this and maybe they'll see reason and allow AUTOINCREMENT fields to do what they are mean to. If they don't, reconsider what makes the valuable as a client.

Comment: @mrhn Because when I saw the `boot` method the `$model` is not directly used in the method but inside `self::creating(function())` method, did you notice that ? So I am confused, how can I get the `$model->id` inside the `next` method ? I don't think `$model` is directly available in the extended `MainModel`, is it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I understand you are confused about how to call statically model queries. You can achieve the same logic by using a static self-reference `static`.

```
public static function next()
{
    return static::max('id') + 1;
}
```

This would be equivalent to.

```
MainModel::max('id');
```

Bonus to make it a transaction to avoid id clashing. This can lock the database in fun ways, but will avoid you have the same ids, something similar to this, very simple example.

```
DB::transaction(function () {
    $id= MainModel::next();

    $newModel = MainModel::create(['id' => $id]);
});
```

Comment: I think i know what you are confused about, but still a little confusing about what the concrete problem is :) else comment and let's take it from there.

Comment: I think you may have just solved my issue. This is the only actual problem that how can I reliably(in most scenario it needs to work, unless there's Mysql server crash) get the Next and Previous ids inside the Model which is linked with weirdly setup table where `AutoIncrement` is `NULL`, which you can verify by running the query `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE '[main_table]';`

Comment: Updated it with a transaction example, that will help you with id clashing, it seems solved? i would not care for the database being down if that happens you have other problems :)

Answer (score -3):

As I understanding, in order to get the next increment id, you need to call the following line.
Model::lastest()->first()